# How to show the $\overline{P_{1}P_{2}}$ intersect $y^2=f(x)=4x^3-g_{2}x-g_{3}$ is $P_{3}=(p(z_{1}+z_{2}),-p'(z_{1}+z_{2}))$

Tags: geometry, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces

> For elliptic curve: $y^2=f(x)=4x^3-g_{2}x-g_{3}$. If $P_{1}=(p(z_{1}),p'(z_{1}))$, $P_{2}=(p(z_{2}),p'(z_{2}))\in f(x)$. How to prove the line $\overline{P_{1}P_{2}}$ intersect with $f(x)$ is $P_{3}=(p(z_{1}+z_{2}),-p'(z_{1}+z_{2}))$.

I have proved it using Veda theorem, but it is too routine. Is there some more simple method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be explained in terms of Weierstrass elliptic function, which has the addition formula: $$\tag{1}\begin{vmatrix} \wp(x) & \wp'(x) & 1 \\ \wp(y) & \wp'(y) & 1 \\ \wp(z) & \wp'(z) & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 0 \qquad \text{ when } x+y+z = 0$$
This says $(\wp(x),\wp'(x))$,$(\wp(y),\wp'(y))$ and $(\wp(x+y),-\wp'(x+y))$ are collinear, note that they all lie on $y^2 = 4x^3-g_2x-g_3$.

$(1)$ can be proved as follows: the determinant, when treated as function of $z$, is an elliptic function of order $3$, hence has $3$ zeroes, their sum is $0$ modulo the lattice. Two zeroes are $x,y$, hence the third must be congruent to $-x-y$.

Comment: Sorry, could you give more details about this addition formula? I do not understand why two zeros are $x,y$?